# Unity - rigidbody MovePosition slows down reaching the target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I want my enemy to follow the player and try to hit it with the full speed but I cant achieve it. It appears to have faster speed value when its far away and slows down while getting closer to the player.
How to make it move at the same speed?

[image]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dotty : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform playerTarget;
    Vector3 direction;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float speed = 2.2f;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        direction = playerTarget.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rb.rotation = angle;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + direction.normalized * speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all change this line :

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + direction.normalized * speed);
```

to this:

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + direction.normalized * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

and the reason it slows down is probably because the target "Z" position is not "0" (same as player "Z" position).